# Host Headers / Site Binding

Tags: iis, iis-7, host-headers

I am going to prefix this that I am a programmer trying to figure out IIS7.  I want to host two sites on my server. I created a second site and gave its own path. I added the two domains I want to forward to in site bindings. For some reason when I got `www.magnetballs.com` I am getting a server not found. What else do I have to do to configure this?

Comment: 1) check spelling 2) make sure that `www` subdomain is created & pointing to the same IP

Comment: Can you post the config please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm getting web page not found (404) as opposed to server not found. Do you have a default document set up for the web site in question and does the default document file exist in the root directory for the web site? If not, that's your problem.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404